# How to deploy a Django production server on IBM Cloud?

Tags: python, django, ibm-cloud, gunicorn

I want to know how to deploy a Django production server on IBM Cloud.

Right now I have a Cloud Foundry Python app running without problems. But I'm using python manage.py runserver to start the app on the cloud.

There is a way to run the app without using the django server? Like, how we do running that kind of apps using Apache o Nginx web servers.

UPDATE:

I tried using the Procfile and gunicorn, but it gives me an error when it starts gunicorn.
This is my Procfile.

```
web: gunicorn my_app.wsgi --workers 2
```

And the error

```
ERR Starting gunicorn 18.0
```

I am using python 3.6 and django 1.11

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Unfortunately, your question has been flagged to be closed because someone feels that it does not meet the quality criteria.   For more information see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Foundry provides out-of-the-box production quality hosting.  You don’t need to configure nginx or apache.  For more information on how cloud foundry works under the hood, see [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/overview.html)

You would however normally configure the method for starting your application. The [python buildback documentation](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/python/index.html) describes a few options, for example:

> **Specify a Start Command**
>
> The Python buildpack does not generate a
>   default start command for your applications.
>
> To stage with the Python buildpack and start an application, do one of
>   the following:
>
> *Required for Cloud Foundry v245 only: Supply a Procfile.*
>
> For more
>   information about Procfiles, see the Configuring a Production Server
>   topic. The following example Procfile specifies gunicorn as the start
>   command for a web app running on Gunicorn:
>
> ```
> web: gunicorn SERVER-NAME:APP-NAME
> ```
>
> *Specify a start command with -c.*
>
> The following
>   example specifies waitress-serve as the start command for a web app
>   running on Waitress:
>
> ```
> $ cf push python-app -c "waitress-serve --port=$PORT DJANGO-WEB-APP.wsgi:MY-APP"
> ```
>
> *Specify a start command in the application manifest by setting the `command` attribute.*
>
> For more
>   information, see the Deploying with Application Manifests topic.

Comment: I tried with this but it gives me errors when the gunicorn starts, so no worker is been created. I have updated my post with the details.

Comment: @MaríaVictoria it looks as though there an example using waitress - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/python-buildpack/tree/db6474a50b99348da6c5256bb2133e03745ffd52/fixtures/django_python_3 - maybe try waitress instead?

Comment: It was a memory error. The memory assigned to the app on IBM Cloud wasn't enough to create the 2 workers. Thanks for your help!